# MIT's Starcluster Errors with too 200+ node

Tags: amazon-ec2, starcluster

Has anybody had issues bringing up cluster sizes larger than 200 nodes? Whenever I try I get the following error:

```
7/dist-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 585, in get_all_instances
   max_results=max_results)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 681, in get_all_reservations
   [('item', Reservation)], verb='POST')
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1186, in get_list
   raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>FilterLimitExceeded</Code><Message>The maximum number of filter values specified on a single call is 200</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>290b6e93-22b4-4450-b487-64d9174d166e</RequestID></Response>
```

I am using the starcluster development branch **0.95.6** because it supports the newer c4 ec2 instances.

Bellow is my star cluster configuration with XXXX's put in place of private information:

```
####################################
## StarCluster Configuration File ##
####################################
[global]

DEFAULT_TEMPLATE=cluster

#############################################
## AWS Credentials and Connection Settings ##
#############################################
[aws info]

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = XXXXXXX
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = XXXXXXXX
AWS_USER_ID=XXXXXX

AWS_REGION_NAME = eu-east-1


###########################
## Defining EC2 Keypairs ##
###########################

[key mykey]
KEY_LOCATION= XXXXXX


################################
## Defining Cluster Templates ##
################################


[cluster cluster]
KEYNAME = mykey
CLUSTER_SIZE = 400
CLUSTER_USER = sgeadmin

CLUSTER_SHELL = bash

NODE_IMAGE_ID = ami-52a0c53b

NODE_INSTANCE_TYPE = c4.large

AVAILABILITY_ZONE = us-east-1a

VOLUMES = cluster, datastore

PERMISSIONS = ssh

SPOT_BID = 0.07



#############################
## Configuring EBS Volumes ##
#############################

[volume cluster]
VOLUME_ID = xxxxx
MOUNT_PATH = /home

[volume datastore]
VOLUME_ID = xxxxx
MOUNT_PATH = /data/


############################################
## Configuring Security Group Permissions ##
############################################

[permission ssh]
IP_PROTOCOL = tcp
FROM_PORT = 22
TO_PORT = 22
```

Comment: Can you paste your Connection.py file?

Comment: Connections.py file: http://pastebin.com/Bx6UrTwt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a StarCluster bug caused by a restriction in the AWS api. StarCluster sends a filtering list containing more than 200 items and that is rejected by AWS. A patch should be made so that StarCluster sends multiple requests instead.